# java - i tried to get view source(html page)

Tags: java

i tried to get view source(html page) from websit 
i used whit this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL url;
        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader br;
        String line;

        try {
            url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
            is = url.openStream();  // throws an IOException
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
             mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
             ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (is != null) is.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // nothing to see here
            }
        }
    }
```

and when i bring to line "is = url.openStream();
i received exception "java.net.UnknownHostException"

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: stackoverflow.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown         Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    at test.main.main(main.java:17)
```

do you know how i can fix this code 
thanks a lot,

Comment: This problem can be caused by the DNS that you're using.

Comment: i checked with some urls like those: "http://google.com" , "http://www.google.com"  , "http://www.google.com/" and again i received the same exception

Comment: Looks like you are behind firewall. Does your browser use a proxy? So should your url reader.

Comment: Looks like you need to set proxy host.